# Generating multiple html tags from one custom tag

Tags: css, html, nested

I basically want to be able to write something like:

```
<mycustomtag>bob</mycustomtag>
```

And have it generate:

```
<div>I'm a template <h2>bob</h2> </div>
```

Is it even possible to do such a thing?

Note that I am not looking to do this with JS, really just plain HTML/CSS. Is such a thing even possible, or can each HTML element not create more via CSS?

Comment: Without javascript (ie [polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/) and such)  I can't really see this being possible

Comment: @Last1Here so there is no "modularity" (of tags, not styles) for lack of a better word in HTML5?

Comment: Nope, I believe it's the way html specs are going though so it maybe soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do such a thing with pure HTML and CSS, you'll need to use JavaScript.

The closest you can do with pure HTML and CSS is by using `::before` and `::after` pseudo-elements:

```
mycustomtag {
  display:block;
}

mycustomtag::after {
  content:'extra element here';
  display:block;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lunu8vve/1/)

Comment: I think this should be enough, but is it just too brittle, or is there some other reason not to use this?

Comment: I don't see why not - it's commonly used now. My only minor concern would be browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Abefore

Comment: And I believe `content` can only be plain text